# python __eq__ and __hash__ functions

Tags: python

When defining a `__hash__` function in python, do I need to worry about some other class's `__hash__` function returning the same value?   I.e., if two different objects of different classes both hash to the same value, is that a problem I need to explicitly consider in my `__hash__` function?

In particular I have a class for which I enforce that it only be instantiated once.  I have defined the `__eq__` and `__hash__` functions like this.  Is this OK?

```py
    def __eq__(self, that):
        return type(self) is type(that)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(0)
```

Comment: That's the whole point of hashes: they are a pretty-much-guaranteed-to-collide digest. However, no, what you implemented isn't very sensible: never return "a fixed value", always base the hash on the actual data in your object, even if it's a singleton object.

Comment: In general, hashes are used for bucketing, but it's not assumed that things with the same hash will always be equal -- there's still an equality check following the hash comparison, when the hashes match.

Comment: *"Is this OK?"* - under what criteria? I don't see how that enforces only one instance if that's what you're asking...

Comment: "if two different objects of different classes both hash to the same value, is that a problem I need to explicitly consider in my `__hash__` function?" no it isn't

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I didn't claim that this was the implementation of singleton class.  That is implemented elsewhere. My question is if I have a singleton class, can I *also* implement the __hash__ function like this.

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans, sorry I don't understand what you are suggesting.  If the hash value is based on a singleton object, isn't it necessarily based on a constant?

Comment: I can't see a reason not to... You need you have a single instance of this class, so it will never clash...

Comment: If you **enforce** that there’s just one instance, doesn’t that mean that the default identity-based comparison/hashing is already correct?

Comment: @DavisHerring,   You could be right. I'm not a python expert enough to know.   I don't understand what the default `==` function does.   Does it allow objects of different types to be equal to each other?    I believe it does, because it seems that `1 == 1.0`, i.e. a float can equal an integer.   One reason that I defined the `__eq__` method was to ensure that anything of a different class be necessarily not equal.   The documentation that I read said that if you ever define `__eq__` you also need to define `__hash__`.   Not sure whether that is good or bad advice.

Comment: @JimNewton: User-defined types by default compare equal only to the same **object** (which necessarily is the same type!).  Certainly defining `__hash__` is good if you really do need to define `__eq__`.

Answer (score 5):

The [`__eq__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) states:

> By default, `object` implements [__eq__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) by using `is`, returning
> `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`.

So in your singleton class case, the default behavior is fine - only references to the same single instance will be deemed equal.

The [`__hash__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) states:

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have
> the same hash value.

Because you're dealing with a single instance, that can only equal itself, it is guaranteed that its own hash value will equal itself. So again, the default is fine for your case.

To seal the deal:

> If a class does not define an [__eq__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method it should not define a
> [__hash__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) operation either; if it defines [__eq__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) but not [__hash__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections.

and:

> User-defined classes have [__eq__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [__hash__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) methods by default;
> with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and
> `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies
> both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

All comes to show that for your use-case, ***there is no need to implement either***.